# Issue in fetching data from pointer data type in parse database using android

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform

I am receiving following json from server with pointer data type

```
[
{
"abc":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"ABC","objectId":"iHHyf1Rerw"}
}
]
```

now how i can fetch other fields from ABC class name. I have tried to fetch with following way:

```
ParseObject obj = parseObject.get(position).getParseObject("abc");
```

now i am trying to fetch

```
obj .getString("colname")
```

but i am getting colname not exists

Answer (score 1):

When you query parse objects with pointer you need to use **include** in order to fetch also the pointer along with the query data.

After you specify the include parse-server will fetch also the pointer data (and not only the reference) so in order to do it you need to write you query in the following way (from parse docs):

[image]

Please notice that there they use **include** in order to also populate the post parse object which exist under the comment so in your case you need to use **query.include("abc")**

Comment: HI Hassid, you answer really helped me alot. Thanks

Comment: I am very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ParseObject obj = parseObject.get(position).getParseObject("abc");
if(obj.has("__type"){
    String type = obj.getString("__type");
}if(obj.has("className"){
    String className = obj.getString("className");
}if(obj.has("objectId"){
    String objectId = obj.getString("objectId");
}
```

Comment: but i know some keys exists in pointed class still i am getting keys not exists so i cannot say this is correct answer.